# Shouldn't the frequency of a tuning fork depend on its shear modulus?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science, moduli

I know that the frequency of a tuning fork depends on its Young's modulus, but intuitively, shouldn't the frequency of a tuning fork depend on it's shear modulus, not it's Young's modulus, as the vibrations involved are essentially a lateral( or parallel to base) movement of the prongs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resonance frequency depends on Young's modulus because the prongs of the tuning fork are bending without shear. Bending is a combination of stretching and compression. The convex side of the prong is stretched, while its concave side is compressed.

A more familiar example of such a combination of stretch and compression is the bending of a bimetallic strip.

Comment: Never thought about it that way. Actually now that i think about the question again it just seems stupid. Thanks anyway.